# Select some data even if a condition isn't me

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to figure this out for a while -- I'm working on a simulation (run in PHP because I hate myself). I've gotten the thing up to the point where I can start adding in "Viruses" and such.

Right now, I'm working on an 'virus' that limits fertility of citizens -- I've got it all working perfectly save for the actual method that finds out if they are 'infertile' or not.

I'm trying to pull data from the database using a query similar to this (**note this query semi-working, but I can't figure out how to make it work properly**):

```
SELECT g.infert1 as gert,
       v.infert1 as vert
FROM genetics as g,
     virus as v,
     citizens as c
WHERE c.cid = 1
  AND g.cid = c.cid
  AND v.vid = c.infected
```

The GERT and VERT data associate to two tables (Genetics and Virus). The virus table contains most of the same rows as the genetics table (Imm00-12, infert1, etc.). Both sets of data select correctly if a 'citizen' is infected, however if they are not, then the result returns null and causes an error.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get conditional data where if a citizen is not infected, it'll still select the GERT information and just return null for VERT as opposed returning nothing at all.

Comment: _using a query similar to this_ How similiar. Its a real pain trying to work on pseudo code. As every step forward normally gets a response of not working, because we cannot see the real code.

Comment: Its also a good idea to setup an SQLFiddle so people have the query and some test data to play with to ensure they give a good and accurate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT genetics.infert1 AS gert,
       virus.infert1 AS vert
FROM citizens
JOIN genetics ON citizens.cid = genetics.cid
LEFT JOIN virus ON virus.vid = citizens.infected
WHERE citizens.cid = 1;
```

This statement starts by performing an `INNER JOIN` between `citizens` and `genetics` based on their common value of `cid`.  This effectively prepends the fields of `citizen` to those of `genetics` for each `citizen`.

It then performs a `LEFT JOIN` between this joined dataset and virus where `virus.vid = citizens.infected`.  This has the effect of appending the values of the fields of a `virus` that a `citizen` is afflicted with along with the fields for that `citizen` to each record from `genetics` for that `citizen`.  If the `citizen` is not afflicted with a `virus`, then `NULL` values are used for the `virus` fields.

The resulting dataset is then refined to just those records where the value of `citizens.cid` is `1`.

If you wish to produce the same list but for all `citizens`, then remove the `WHERE` clause.

Using `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` and is a more modern and efficient way of joining than using `CROSS JOIN`'s refined by the `WHERE` clause.  A `CROSS JOIN` between two tables, performed using `tblTable1, tblTable2` appends a copy of every record from `tblTable2` to every record from `tblTable`.  The resulting (often very large) dataset is then refined by the `WHERE` clause.  With `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` only those record that meet the `ON` criteria are joined, which is typically significantly faster.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: While creditable, I fear with such a lengthy answer we are in danger of using up the internet.

Comment: This was the solution! thank you. I'm still trying to wrap my head around joins (I understand every other function of SQL at this point, save for them). Thankee-sai!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to be of help.  I have found https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to be of help in understanding joins, especially the Venn diagram and the links below this one in the left-most column.  Have you tried searching the web for `join sql` or `join mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is probably what you want.

```
SELECT g.infert1 as gert,
       cv.vert as vert
FROM
    genetics as g
LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT c.cid as cid, v.infert1 as vert
      FROM virus as v
      INNER JOIN citizens as c ON v.vid = c.infected 
      WHERE c.cid = 1
      ) AS cv
        ON g.cid = cv.cid
```

Here I use SQL JOIN syntax:

- Inner Join means give me rows where they exactly match.  Which is what your orignal SQL does, but we want that only on virus vs citizens
- LEFT JOIN means "give me rows from the LEFT hand table, and if there are any in the other, then include them too"  - which is what I think you want.

You may wish to re-evaluate whether citizens can only have one virus though.